# Making sidewalk from street center lines

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I have downloaded from OSM the cartography from a village in Germany and it doesn't have the sidewalk but instead the street center lines.

Is there any way to make like in OSM?

I mean, something like this:

[image]

I have tried with some buffer options but it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: What you show as "What I want" is the center line that is symbolized as a thick white line with thin grey border, this doesn't show sidewalk and is not an accurate representation of street width. Could you explain in more detail what you exactly want ?

Comment: Yes, I know it is the thickness, but I want that representation as a proper line or a polygon, because after that, I want to migrate the geometries to autocad. The tool buffer makes what I want but only with simple lines, with complex structure it makes a mess. Something like this but with the roads will be great 
https://postimg.cc/Z09xqBw9 
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Did you try the buffer tool with the "Dissolve result" option if yes could you show us the result with what is wrong

Comment: Yes, I can show you the proccesss that I follow. 
Original lines: https://i.postimg.cc/02JHzt5j/image.png
Buffer: https://i.postimg.cc/jdP0pq7M/image.png
Result: https://i.postimg.cc/FKK6HhY5/imag